# Invalid operation exception when passing JSON string

Tags: c#, jquery, json

This is what I have done

```
        bool query = ( from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et
                where n.BeginDate == b
                where n.EndDate == e
                select n).Count()>0;

       var dupli = (from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                     where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et
                     where n.BeginDate == b
                     where n.EndDate == e
                     select n);
        if (query)
        {
         return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dupli);
        }
        else
        {
            return "No duplicate";
        }
```

When I try to convert it into a JSON string, I get a circular reference error. The error occurs at the Serialize step. So, I think probably I get an error because it is an invalid object or something. Do I need to use something like Iqueryable or something. Please help me in getting rid of this error?

Comment: off topic: use `.Any()` extension instead of `Count() > 0`

Comment: Any reason you have multiple `where`s instead of just using `&&`, or defining `dupli` outside of the scope in which you use it?

Comment: dupli can be defined inside if.... Let me try that one..

Comment: @Bala: Ya can use Any()... I'll use that

Comment: @Cory: No use, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a little more straightforward. Also, you might need a concrete set of objects in order to serialize them (instead of an `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` that you're getting from the LINQ query, so I threw in a `.ToList()` to get a `List<T>`, where `T` is whatever type is in your `NCDCPoints` collection. This is completely untested, just so you know.

To avoid the circular reference you mentioned, you can use the technique I added to the LINQ query:

```
var query = (from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
             where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et && n.BeginDate == b && n.EndDate == e
             select new 
             {
                 EventTypeId = n.EVENT_TYPE_ID,
                 BeginDate = n.BeginDate,
                 EndDate = n.EndDate,
                 ... // add the other properties you need on the client side
             });

if (query.Any())
{
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(query.ToList());
}
else
{
    return "No duplicate";
}
```

Comment: @Cory: I still get the same error of circular reference(which is some type invalid operation exception)..

Comment: `JavascriptSerializer` uses reflection to serialize your list, but you must have a property that points back to the `CDC.NCDCPoints` list. A collection can't be serialized if it has circular references.

Comment: @Carlson: Oh... So Can u please tell me another way to do this?

Comment: K... I have 50 fields in there. So, Do i have any other way to proceed with this one.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran across the same problem, I did a quick research on why this happens on Entity Framework and came across a wonderful answer at Stack Overflow itself.

Read this: [Is this bug ?...got reason behind circular reference ... how to solve but?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887101/is-this-bug-got-reason-behind-circular-reference-how-to-solve-but/4918571#4918571)

> You should never serialize the LINQ to
>   SQL (or Entity Framework) classes.
>   Even though Microsoft has placed
>   [DataContract] and other attributes on
>   these classes, they should not be
>   serialized.
>
> Instead, design a set of classes that
>   correctly matches what you want to
>   have serialized.

Try these steps.

1. Create a mock class called NCDCPointsMock

   ```
   public class NCDCPointsMock
   {
       public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }
       public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
       public int EVENT_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
       // add another dfields you might have in the original NCDCPoints class
       //example        
       //public int ID { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Now modify your code like this.

   ```
   var query = CDC.NCDCPoints
       .Select(n => n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et 
           && n.BeginDate == b 
           && n.EndDate == e );
   if (query.Any())
   {
       var points = query.ToList();]
       List<NCDCPointsMock> duplicates = new List<NCDCPointsMock>();
       foreach(var point in points)
       {
           NCDCPointsMock dupli = new NCDCPointsMock();
           dupli.ID = point.ID;
           dupli.BeginDate = point.BeginDate;
           dupli.EndDate = point.EndDate;
           dupli.EVENT_TYPE_ID = point.EVENT_TYPE_ID;
           duplicates.Add(dupli);
       }
       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dupli);
   }
   else
   {
       return "No duplicate";
   }
   ```

Or you can try something from here. But that will make the model different from database.

[LINQ to SQL and Serialization](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/02/LINQ-to-SQL-and-Serialization)

Comment: hey..My problem is that I have so many fields in the NCDCPoints. And they are dynamic. So, apart from serialization , do i have any other way of doing this?

Comment: @nishanth yeddula: actually i wouldn't have posted this if i had seen cory's answer before hand. slightly different approach but in effect the same.